# Smart but mountable diskimager for windows (that works like ntfsclone -o but in windows)

Tags: windows, mount, backup, cloning, hard-drive

I like ntfsclone -o image.img because it is mountable.
However it is not a windows app.

Is there a nice windows solution that:

A)Does file mode partition or drive copying (for NTFS).

B)Image that can be mounted with say ntfs-3g (not some special format basically)

This just means one can image files on windows while it's going (maybe not C:) and then latter manipulate those file with tools like dd, winimage etc on your OS of choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://web.archive.org/web/20080630053926/http://selfimage.excelcia.org/
Seems to do all that I want but the project is dead :S I hope it's reliable.

Very nice tool if it works.

http://offload1.icculus.org:9090/~kfitzner/selfimage/SelfImage-121.zip
It contains an easy exe installer.

It's GPL so if anyone want's to revive a project....

Please add others here.  For example if you know of say a currently supported project.

Comment: Tested on NTFS works so far, FAT doesn't see to image with any intelligences (same md5 as dd) but only had one go at it.

Comment: I don't know if these guys are using ntfsclone or what does anyone know a windows port of ntfs clone or another project for windows that isn't dead?